# Dealing with a daily time window across timezones in Node.js

Tags: node.js, timezone, momentjs, utc, timezone-offset

Currently, I'm working on a project that requires a window of time to be selected that is used as a valid window to trigger an event within. This window is selected by the user as a start time (24 hour time), end time (24 hour time), and a timezone. My goal is to then be able to convert these times into UTC based on the offset from the provided timezone and save into MySQL.

The main problem is I have set up the entire flow to deal with time-only data types from the mobile app all the way back to the MySQL database. I have been trying to figure out a solution that won't require changing all those data types to include date and time which would require changes in many parts of the project.

Can I make this calculation without dealing with the date? I don't believe I can as timezone offsets range from -12:00 to +14:00 which would push some windows to the next or previous days when turned into UTC.

Is the correct approach to add in the date component and then continue to update it as time progresses? I also want to ensure daylight savings doesn't create errors.

Ultimately I would like the best approach to take so if I have to change a lot now I'd rather do that then deal with a headache later. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!